# If timer running function

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

Hi I am making countdowntimer where while my timer running my app read me boxing combination and I made a dialog where after click button I see " are you sure to quit" and after click yes my app goes to previously activity but still reading combination. And here is my question I would like to cancel my running countdown or  make function if(my timer running) { read combos} for example. Is it possible? My code looks

```
 timerodkombosa = new CountDownTimer(dłrundy, 5000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {




                    
                    final Random rand = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
                    tv3.setText(kombosy[new Random().nextInt(kombosy.length)]);
                    switch (tv3.getText().toString()) {
                        case "1-2":
                            MediaPlayer ring = MediaPlayer.create(Main3Activity.this, R.raw.rin1);
                            ring.start();
                            break;
                        case "1-1-2":
                            MediaPlayer ring2 = MediaPlayer.create(Main3Activity.this, R.raw.rin2);
                            ring2.start();
                            break;
                        case "1-2-3-2":
                            MediaPlayer ring3 = MediaPlayer.create(Main3Activity.this, R.raw.rin3);
                            ring3.start();
                            break;
                        case "1-2-5-2":
                            MediaPlayer ring4 = MediaPlayer.create(Main3Activity.this, R.raw.rin4);
                            ring4.start();
                            break;
                        case "1-6-3-2":
                            MediaPlayer ring5 = MediaPlayer.create(Main3Activity.this, R.raw.rin5);
                            ring5.start();
                            break;
                        case "2-3-2":
                            MediaPlayer ring6 = MediaPlayer.create(Main3Activity.this, R.raw.rin6);
                            ring6.start();
                            break;

                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onFinish() {


                    tv3.setText("");
                    if (licz > 1) {

                        round_count1[0]++;
                        if (round_count1[0] < finalNum_rounds) {
                            Handler handler = new Handler();
                            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    start();
                                }
                            }, dłprzerwy);


                             timerodprzerwy = new CountDownTimer(dłprzerwy, 1000) {
                                @Override
                                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                    mTimeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
                                    updatetext();
                                }
                                @Override
                                public void onFinish() {
                                }
                            }.start();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.start();
        }
    }.start();
```

Comment: You can try cancelling the timers with CountDownTimer.cancel() or if you want to exit the application completely you can use System.exit()

Comment: But when I write  CountDownTimer.cancel() my my app still reading this combos in background